# How can i get access_token and then use it?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-java-api, facebook-java-sdk

In my web application i want users to login with their facebook account. I am doing it by redirecting url.

```
 response.sendRedirect("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=email,user_about_me&dispplay=popup&client_id={app_id}&redirect_uri=http://example.com/index.jsp&response_type=token");
```

At index.jsp i am getting access_token in url. But in request there is no access token. how can i get access token here and then fetch user email. url at index.jsp looks like this:

```
  http://example.com/index.jsp#access_token={access_token}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial and it solved my problem. Following is the link of that turorial:

http://pinoyphp.blogspot.com/2010/12/oath-tutorial-how-to-get-facebook.html#comment-form

Answer (score 2):

I actually just got this working in my JSP project!  Ok Here is what you need to know.  The method you are trying for is called the "Server Side" approach (there is also a Client Side approach which can share a lot of the same code.  There are two URLs that you will use (I've wrapped this all into a helper classed I've called FacebookConfig which reads what it needs from a facebook.properties file:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import lombok.Cleanup;
import st.fan.model.users.Listener;

public class FacebookConfig {
  public static String auth_uri;
  public static String id;
  public static String key;

  static{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
      @Cleanup InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("facebook.properties");
      properties.load(in);
      auth_uri = (String)properties.get("auth_uri");
      id = (String)properties.get("id");
      key = (String)properties.get("key");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static String getOAuthDialogUrl() {
    return "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="+id+"&redirect_uri="+auth_uri+"&scope=email";
  }

  public static String getOAuthUrl(String code) {
    return "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+id+"&redirect_uri="+auth_uri+"&client_secret="+key+"&code="+code;
  }

  public static String getGraphUrl(String token) {
    return "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="+token;
  }

  public static String getProfilePictureUrl(Listener profile) {
    return "https://graph.facebook.com/"+profile.getFacebookId()+"/picture";
  }

  public static String getProfilePictureUrl(Listener profile, String size) {
    return "https://graph.facebook.com/"+profile.getFacebookId()+"/picture?type="+size;
  }
}
```

Now the user is redirected to the getOAuthDialogUrl() which includes the URL of a servlet called http://example.com/auth/facebook/Auth which has this doGet() method

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
  Transaction tx = null;
  Session dao = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
  String redirect = "/auth/facebook/sorry";

  try {
    String code = request.getParameter("code");
    if(code != null) {
      String[] pairs = NetUtils.fetch(new URL(FacebookConfig.getOAuthUrl(code))).toString().split("&");
      String accessToken = null;
      Integer expires = null;
      for (String pair : pairs) {
        String[] kv = pair.split("=");
        if (kv.length == 2) {
          if (kv[0].equals("access_token")) {
            accessToken = kv[1];
          }
          if (kv[0].equals("expires")) {
            expires = Integer.valueOf(kv[1]);
          }
        }
      }
      if(accessToken != null && expires != null) {
        try {
          JSONObject fb_profile = new JSONObject(NetUtils.fetch(new URL(FacebookConfig.getGraphUrl(accessToken))));
          tx = dao.beginTransaction();
          ListenerSession session = authenticate(request, dao);
          if(session == null) {
            session = createSession(response, dao);
          }
          String facebookid = fb_profile.getString("id");
          String name = fb_profile.getString("name");
          String email = fb_profile.getString("email");
          String username = facebookid;
          if(fb_profile.has("username")) {
            username = fb_profile.getString("username");
          }
          Listener user = ListenerDAO.findByFacebookId(facebookid, dao);
          if(user != null) {
            user.setDisplayName(name);
            user.setEmail(email);
            dao.save(user);
          } else {
            user = new Listener();
            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setDisplayName(name);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setDateCreated(new DateTime());
            user.setFacebookId(facebookid);
            user.setStatus(ListenerStatus.ACTIVE);
            dao.save(user);
          }
          ListenerSessionDAO.link(session, user, dao);
          redirect = "/";
          tx.commit();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          log.error("Parsing Facebook Graph Response", e);
        }
      } else {
        log.error("Expected values not found!");
        log.error("accessToken="+accessToken);
        log.error("expires="+expires);
      }
    } else {
      log.error("Missing 'code' param!");
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
  } finally {
    if(dao.isOpen()) {
      dao.close();
    }
  }
  response.sendRedirect(redirect);
}
```

And (in addition to using Hibernate, Project Lombok and a simple JSON library called org.json) I use a simple helper function called fetch() which takes a URL and returns the contents as a string which has this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class NetUtils {
  public static String fetch(URL url) throws IOException {
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      builder.append(line);
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
}
```

This should get you off the ground :)

Comment: From where can i get st.fan.model.users.Listener jar?

Comment: I got this far after implementing an answer to this question I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184959/facebook-connect-example-in-jsp-tomcat the Listener class is basically the Profile class I talked about.

Answer (score 1):

The [facebook authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) shows that you should get the token as request parameter. Just don't use `response_type=token`

Comment: ok. I used response_type=code. and i got code as a request parameter. Now how to get the token?

Comment: http://pinoyphp.blogspot.com/2010/12/oath-tutorial-how-to-get-facebook.html  i found this tutorial but i have little bit confused. i got code but then how can i get access_token. if i try to redirect it to some other servlet then it gives error. It means that request_uri should be same for getting code and access_token. and how is it possible? It will be like infinite calls to same page. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

just print the $_REQUEST['signed_request'] array and there is oauth in it . that is your active access token use it where you want..

I myself spend two days on it and finally got it