# Why I am getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and how to get rid of that?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, servlets

I am making a web application using google app engine. I was not using GWT before. But for some reason now i want to use Window.Location.getHref(). I added GWT SDK and all gwt jars file . But now when i call Window.Location.getHref(), i get java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. Here is the log:

```
  2011-08-23 01:17:22.193 /indexpage 500 543ms 1423cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U;      Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1
  90.230.245.85 - - [23/Aug/2011:01:17:22 -0700] "GET /indexpage HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "http://runnotest.appspot.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1" "runnotest.appspot.com" ms=544 cpu_ms=1423 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.039580 instance=00c61b117c2bd11a01e44ceafe4dc9ee198fb4
  W 2011-08-23 01:17:22.183
  Error for /indexpage
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Window$Location.getHash(Window.java:172)
at com.eplinovo.runno3test.mahmood.action.IndexPageServlet.doGet(IndexPageServlet.java:27)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:262)
at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$2.handleRequest(RuntimePb.java:9819)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.handleRequest(RpcUtil.java:445)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:414)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:579)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:694)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:332)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:324)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:452)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:92)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.<clinit>(Window.java:508)
... 38 more
  W 2011-08-23 01:17:22.185
  Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:92)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.<clinit>(Window.java:508)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Window$Location.getHash(Window.java:172)
at com.eplinovo.runno3test.mahmood.action.IndexPageServlet.doGet(IndexPageServlet.java:27)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:262)
at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$2.handleRequest(RuntimePb.java:9819)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.handleRequest(RpcUtil.java:445)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:414)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:579)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:694)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:332)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:324)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:452)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
  C 2011-08-23 01:17:22.186
  Uncaught exception from servlet
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Window$Location.getHash(Window.java:172)
at com.eplinovo.runno3test.mahmood.action.IndexPageServlet.doGet(IndexPageServlet.java:27)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:262)
at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$2.handleRequest(RuntimePb.java:9819)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.handleRequest(RpcUtil.java:445)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:414)
at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:579)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:694)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:332)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:324)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:452)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:92)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.<clinit>(Window.java:508)
... 38 more
```

Any idea why i am getting java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and how to get rid of that? Thanks in advance.

here is the code:

```
 public class IndexPageServlet extends HttpServlet {
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    try
    {

        String token = Window.Location.getHref();
        out.println("Token: " + token);

                    // .... rest of the code

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         System.out.println("Error fetching runs: " + ex);
    }

    finally
    {
        pm.close();
    }

}
 }
```

Comment: Could you post the actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server, you are referring to a class which calls `GWT.create()` in a static block. You can't do that.

The problem in your code is `Window.Location.getHref()` - this is *not* available on the server. If you want to get the current url, use `request.getRequestURL()` from the serlvet api.

You can't access anchor parameters on the server (`#foo`). They are not sent from the client. You have to parse them on the client and send them as request parameters.

Comment: I just configured GWT sdk and called Window.Location.getHref(). Is GWT.create() is called on server. any solution to avoid that and make it work?

Comment: Problem is my url has a token and its look like this : http://www.example.com/index#access_token={access_token}. By calling that function i can not get the part of url after #

Comment: you can't access that on the server. You have to send it as a request parameter.

Comment: infact i am trying to get login on my web application with facebook account. for that i am using this: response.sendRedirect("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=email,user_about_me&dispplay=popup&client_id=2343234343433&redirect_uri=http://example.com/indexpage&response_type=token");   which asks for my user name and password and then redirect me to indexPage. How can i send that token as request parameter in this situation?

Comment: infact i am trying to get login on my web application with facebook account. for that i am using this: response.sendRedirect("facebook.com/dialog/oauth/…;); which asks for my user name and password and then redirect me to indexPage. How can i send that token as request parameter in this situation?

Comment: that's a completely different question now ;)

Comment: yeah it is. infact i put a question yesterday. If you have any idea about that then please give your answer on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146876/how-can-i-get-access-token-and-then-use-it    Its will be really great for me. Thanks