# How to post text from my Web app to my Facebook Fans Page?

Tags: facebook

I want to post some text data to my Facebook fans page from my web application.

How can I do that?

Can anyone give me some guidelines.

Thanks in Advance,
Jerry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use graph API.You can create a post on a Page by issuing an HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/feed with the publish_stream and manage_pages permissions

More at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts

Comment: Thank you Angel for your quick Reply. I am new to graph API. Is there any need of web servises because my web application is developed by JSP.

Comment: Most welcome .you can read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184959/facebook-connect-example-in-jsp-tomcat  for that .I am using graph api in php.You have to find a java version of sdk.