# How to use facebook login openid?

Tags: facebook, openid

The goal is for people who use facebook to easily login to our website, not to necessarily integrate with facebook and add things to it (yet). I have read the documentation on facebook connect and am still having trouble grasping exactly what we need to do to accomplish this. I referred the link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

To solve your query , there some examples here.You can refer those example for how it is done.The concept is same here as well.The following example uses facebook login scenario in an application set up in Tomcat servlet engine.

[Facebook Connect example in JSP (tomcat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184959/facebook-connect-example-in-jsp-tomcat)

Hope this help you.

Comment: here i'm using C#. Is there any C# examples with you?