# Spring Oauth2 login - anonymous not allowed?

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2

Following the [manual](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) I achieve to connect to the Facebook graph API and retrieve info from the user. The problem comes when I wanted give access (Login) with Facebook, I got this error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:565) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.getForObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.controllers.FacebookController.login(FacebookController.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
```

The error clearly said "anonymous user is not allow to obtain an access token". Of course the user is anonymous and is trying to authenticate. How can I do it then? maybe what I do at the controller is not the correct way of login?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/facebookLogin")
@ResponseBody
public User login() {
    ObjectNode result = facebookRestTemplate
            .getForObject(
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=name,email,third_party_id",
                    ObjectNode.class);
    ...
}
```

I'm using `spring-security:4.0.1.RELEASE` and `spring-security-oauth2:2.0.7.RELEASE`

Note: In this scenario I use facebook but the problem should appear also with google, twitter, etc.

Comment: hi please verify my answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you've shared doesn't show the login, it only shows when you are trying to retrieve information about the user.

According to the Spring documentation you need to adapt the client for it to be able to work with FB.

> Some external OAuth2 providers (e.g. Facebook) do not quite implement
>   the specification correctly, or else they are just stuck on an older
>   version of the spec than Spring Security OAuth. To use those providers
>   in your client application you might need to adapt various parts of
>   the client-side infrastructure.
>
> To use Facebook as an example, there is a Facebook feature in the
>   tonr2 application (you need to change the configuration to add your
>   own, valid, client id and secret - they are easy to generate on the
>   Facebook website).

There is a response to another thread about how to do it in a Servlet page [Facebook Connect example in JSP (tomcat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184959/facebook-connect-example-in-jsp-tomcat/5265028#5265028)

And here is a copy of another solution on how to do it in an MVC implementation:

```
public ActionResult Authenticate()
        {
                var oauthFacebook = new FacebookOAuth();
                if (Request["code"] == null)
                {
                    //Redirect the user to Facebook for authorization.
                    Response.Redirect(oauthFacebook.AuthorizationLinkGet());
                }
                else
                {
                    //Get the access token and secret.
                    oauthFacebook.AccessTokenGet(Request["code"]);
                    if (oauthFacebook.Token.Length > 0)
                    {
                        //We can now make our api calls
                        var user = oauthFacebook.GetAttributes();
                    }
                }
        }

public class FacebookOAuth : Oauth
    {
        public FacebookOAuth()
        {
            Authorize = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize";
            AccessToken = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
            CallbackUrl = "http://<YourURLHere>/Authenticate";
            AttributesBaseUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=";
            ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookConsumerKey"];//Ur Consumer Key goes here
            ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookConsumerSecret"];//Ur Consumer secret goes here
            Provider = "Facebook";
        }

        public override string AuthorizationLinkGet()
        {
            return
                string.Format(
                    "{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&scope=email,user_education_history,user_location,user_hometown",
                    Authorize, ConsumerKey, CallbackUrl);
        }

        public User GetAttributes()
        {
            string attributesUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", AttributesBaseUrl, Token);
            string attributes = WebRequest(Method.Get, attributesUrl, String.Empty);
            var FacebookUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FacebookUser>(attributes);
            return new User()
            {
                FirstName = FacebookUser.first_name,
                MiddleName = FacebookUser.middle_name,
                LastName = FacebookUser.last_name,
                Locale = FacebookUser.locale,
                UserEmail = FacebookUser.email,
                AuthProvider = Provider,
                AuthToken=Token
            };
        }
    }
public abstract class Oauth
    {
        #region Method enum

        public enum Method
        {
            Get,
            Post,
            Delete
        } ;

        #endregion

        protected string AccessToken;
        protected string AttributesBaseUrl;
        protected string Authorize;
        protected string CallbackUrl;
        protected string ConsumerKey;
        protected string ConsumerSecret;
        public string Provider { get; protected set; }

        public string Token { get; set; }

        public virtual string AuthorizationLinkGet()
        {
            return
                string.Format(
                    "{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&scope=publish_stream,email,user_education_history,user_location",
                    Authorize, ConsumerKey, CallbackUrl);
        }

        public void AccessTokenGet(string authToken)
        {
            Token = authToken;
            string accessTokenUrl = string.Format("{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&client_secret={3}&code={4}",
                                                  AccessToken, ConsumerKey, CallbackUrl, ConsumerSecret, authToken);
            string response = WebRequest(Method.Get, accessTokenUrl, String.Empty);

            if (response.Length > 0)
            {
                //Store the returned access_token
                NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response);

                if (qs["access_token"] != null)
                {
                    Token = qs["access_token"];
                }
            }
        }

        public string WebRequest(Method method, string url, string postData)
        {
            StreamWriter requestWriter;
            string responseData = string.Empty;

            var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.Method = method.ToString();
                webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                webRequest.Timeout = 20000;

                if (method == Method.Post)
                {
                    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    //POST the data.
                    requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
                    try
                    {
                        requestWriter.Write(postData);
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        requestWriter.Close();
                    }
                }
                responseData = WebResponseGet(webRequest);
            }
            return responseData;
        }

        public string WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            StreamReader responseReader = null;
            string responseData;
            try
            {
                responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (webRequest != null) webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
                if (responseReader != null) responseReader.Close();
            }
            return responseData;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The point is, how can I retrieve "the minimal" info to validate/authenticate the user at my webapp using the `spring-security-oauth2` library, I had done what `Torn2` does (retrieve info) but I'm only allow if I'm authenticated on `spring-security`. As I said doesn't matter if is Facebook or other provider. Doesn't make sense use `spring-security-oauth2` if I have to reimplement every thing just to login. I don't if I have expressed myself well. thanks for answer

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the bad thing is that facebook doesn't comply with the oauth2 spec. That's why you have to re implement this things, I know that you want a standard way of handling it but unless FB changes on their side (I don't think they will) we are stuck with this.

Comment: the same scenario with google give me the same exception `InsufficientAuthenticationException`

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this code in the tonr2 project

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/tonr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/config/WebMvcConfig.java

```
@Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails facebook() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        details.setId("facebook");
        details.setClientId("233668646673605");
        details.setClientSecret("33b17e044ee6a4fa383f46ec6e28ea1d");
        details.setAccessTokenUri("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token");
        details.setUserAuthorizationUri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth");
        details.setTokenName("oauth_token");
        details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
        details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
        return details;
    }
```

Add you facebook credentials accordingly on OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails .
Then this bean will be referred by the Spring Security OAuth AuthenticationProvider,when you will try to get data from facebook which is automatically detected once the FacebookController tries to access FB data.
But you have to understand the config below:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/tonr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/config/SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("marissa").password("wombat").roles("USER").and().withUser("sam")
                .password("kangaroo").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/sparklr/**","/facebook/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.jsp")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .loginPage("/login.jsp")
                .failureUrl("/login.jsp?authentication_error=true")
                .permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

Lets say you will be using the tonr2 application, the inMemoryAuthentication provides authentication on Spring security using the user "marissa" and password "wombat". So in your ui, try to authenticate first against Spring Security.
Once authenticated, you will have the role "USER". Only this time you will be allowed then to access the resource named FaceBookController that tries to retrieve data from facebook itself, refer to this code segment,

```
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/sparklr/**","/facebook/**").hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
```

So just adjust the code accordingly.

**UPDATE**

Take Note: The given Spring Security sample application is not configured yet to have dynamic client secret key, it still hard coded using a single secret key in the OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails just to demonstrate it simply. Dynamic facebook client secret key retrieval from a authenticated facebook user needs additional more steps. Or if you want to just to test the facebook retrieval, adjust the code above to something like this,

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
```

Remove the restriction that requires the user to have a role USER and just allow all requests without the need to authenticate on Spring Security first.