# Spring and OAuth2 in non-interactive mode, with client_credentials grant type

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

I have a REST service that uses OAuth2 authentication and that provides an endpoint to request a token with the client_credentials grant type. The application is based on Spring Boot.

So far I figured out I can request a token with something like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class App extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    //...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Does nothing - to allow unrestricted access
    }    

    @Bean
    protected OAuth2RestTemplate myTemplate() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails details = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        details.setAccessTokenUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token");
        details.setClientId("theClient");
        details.setClientSecret("thePassword");
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, oauth2ClientContext);
    }

}

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2RestTemplate myTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/token")
    private String getToken() {
        return myTemplate.getAccessToken().getValue();
    }

}
```

And it *almost* works, but whenever I call the `/token` endpoint, there's an exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ...
```

The exception is thrown [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/AccessTokenProviderChain.java#L89), but I'm not sure how I can make Spring use context authentication other than `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`. In fact, I don't want any authentication from the client, because anonymous is perfectly okay. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why you need to use Client_Creds flow then, as Client_Creds always uses certain credentials

Comment: It's a good question, but that's how the service is implemented: you can only connect to it using a token, which is provided by this same service, and the token is obtained via OAuth2.

Comment: I guess you are looking for anonymous authentication, Look at other questions on anonymous authentication support in Spring Security

Comment: Just take a look at this question, if this can help you out, [Spring Oauth2 login - anonymous not allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110491/spring-oauth2-login-anonymous-not-allowed)