# Connect facebook in Web App using OAuth Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, oauth-2.0, webserver

I have been searching all over the internet on how to get Access Token from user using java language and finally I found one by using Servlet.

But seems I cannot implement this servlet easily.

As per what Mat B. said on [this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184959/facebook-connect-example-in-jsp-tomcat) servlet is the solution for this. But How do I call/ run this servlet class?

I have been searching for days now but I couldn't find a working solution for me.
I tried calling it from my jsp but it won't work that easily since I am using a framework and my jsp looks like this:

```
<f:view>
<h:form>
<f:subview id="lgwfacebookg_sv">
<t:beanprocessing id="g_1" >
<t:clienthttpsender id="g_2" />
<t:jshowurl id="g_3" target="_blank" trigger="#{d.lgwfacebook.browserTrigger}" url="#{d.lgwfacebook.browserUrl}" usedesktop="true" />
<t:timer id="g_4" duration="1000" durationtype="regular" />
</t:beanprocessing>
<t:rowtitlebar id="g_5" />
<t:rowheader id="g_6" />
<t:rowbodypane id="g_7" >
<t:row id="g_8" >
<t:label id="g_9" text="#{d.lgwfacebook.name}" />
</t:row>
<t:row id="g_10" >
<t:button id="g_11" actionListener="#{d.lgwfacebook.onRedirectUrl}" image="/images/fbimg.png" />
</t:row>
<t:rowdistance id="g_12" height="20" />
</t:rowbodypane>
<t:pageaddons id="g_pa"/>
</f:subview>
</h:form>
</f:view>
```

I already included it in web.xml

```
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>MainMenu</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>managedbeans.MainMenu</servlet-class> 
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>MainMenu</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/MainMenu</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

How do I run this servlet? I'm running apache tomcat.

Comment: Why not just use javascript?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte I am using a framework, I cannot use javascript in it